# Live refresh shows "modified" on tagged questions even when unmodified

Tags: bug, live-refresh, new-questions

I commonly review [questions tagged delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi), sorted by newest, and just now it showed "1 question with new activity":

> [image: live refresh indicator]

So as always, I clicked on that bar to show it. [And I noticed that this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815351/delphi-xe5-center-android-layout) showed here as "modified".

> [image]

But yet, when I opened it up, it didn't show that it was modified.

It's my understanding that if you modify your question within the first minute or so, it doesn't show as a modification. The OP did in fact quickly edit their question right after asking it, after I asked them.

Shouldn't this say "asked" for instead of "modified"?

After refreshing, it shows "asked". But when I clicked on the message to show new activity, it showed "modified".

Comment: Are you sure you were on the newest tab? I've never seen a "modified" prefix there. That only shows up in the "active" tab, where it *always* displays "modified" no matter what.

Comment: @animuson Yes, I always watch the Newest tab. Just confirmed.

Comment: I know downvotes mean nothing here, but I don't understand why I must get one on this.

Comment: Don't know either; I've reproduced this, and it sure seems like a bug to me. I've edited again to emphasize that this appears only when using live refresh - and I'll further note that it doesn't matter if the question was stealth-edited, *all* live-refreshed questions show up as "modified..."

Comment: Yeah, now that I've been watching, every single question that comes up says "modified"